# Dealing with 360-degree wraparound when plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I apologize if something like this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it in my searching.

I am plotting data on a matplotlib plot by feeding a LineCollection artist a segment derived from arrays of azimuth/elevation points:

```
points = np.array([info['azimuth_values'], info['elevation_values']]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[increment][:-1], points[increment][1:]], axis=1)
```

This is working mostly fine and producing lines on the graph, but sometimes the line reaches the end of the plot's x-axis (360 deg.) and will, instead of neatly continuing on the opposite side of the x-axis (0 deg.), plot a line horizontally across to the other side, causing issues with some of the evaluations I am using the plot for as well as not looking particularly visually pleasing.

Here's a mock-up of what I'm talking about:

[image: mock-up]

I want it to do the following:

[image: this].

How can I implement a fix to prevent it from doing that annoying jump across the plot?

Also: I know a LineCollection may not be optimal for the single-line plot I am creating, but I am editing an existing codebase and am hesitant to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the modulo (`%`) of degrees to the plot function, the value passed will always be between 0-359

```
x_deg %= 360
```

Update:
Looking at your diagram, you may need to detect this wrap-around (e.g. `x_deg % 360 != x_deg`) and then create a new line/plot object.

Comment: The data, due to how it was captured, is all between 0 and 360 anyway. My issue is with when the line transitions from 360 back to 0. Will this solution still work?

Comment: You accepted the answer - were you able to 1. detect the loop-around and 2. create 2 line segments?

Comment: I suppose I should make 100% sure it works first, but, theoretically, I'm quite sure it will work. I'll re-mark it as an answer once I am able to implement it.

Comment: If data is always between 0-359, there are ways you could conceivably massage a condition to make that line-segment change/split (dy<<dx, etc), but the more general you need your code to be (and esp if data input is not in increasing-elevation order), the harder it gets.

Comment: I eventually figured it out. The plot was set up using a LineCollection of multiple segments implicitly connected together. I was able to set up a condition to detect the occasions where it wrapped back around from 0->360 or 360->0 and simply delete those segments. It got more complicated later due to having to also edit how a scatterplot interacted with the data, but your suggestion of detecting the wraparound when it happens was very helpful.